# Регулярные выражения c \w

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения, строки

Хочу проверять строку на соответствие шаблону с помощью `Regex.IsMatch`. Строка должна содержать только буквы, цифры и "_". Как я понял, для такой задачи подойдёт шаблон `@"(\w)"`. Однако когда я так пишу, IsMatch выдаёт true на любые символы. Если писать `@"(\w)$"` то ситуация улучшается, и IsMatch выдаёт false если в конце строки будут не те символ, но это не решает проблему неверных символов в начале и середине строки. Если же писать `@"^(\w)$"` то IsMatch всегда false возвращает.

В общем подскажите как мне написать шаблон правильно.

Comment: Вот так? ```@"^\w+$"```

Comment: Круто, вроде работает, благодарю!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Строка должна содержать только буквы, цифры и "_".*

Обратите внимание на то, что `\w` на самом деле означает

| Категория | Описание |
| --- | --- |
| Ll | Буква: строчные буквы |
| Lu | Буква: прописные буквы |
| Lt | Буква: заглавный регистр |
| Lo | Буква: другие |
| Lm | Буква: модификатор |
| Mn | Метка: не занимающая место |
| Nd | Число: десятичная цифра |
| Pc | Пунктуация, соединитель. Эта категория включает десять символов, наиболее часто используемым из которых является знак подчеркивания (_), u+005F. |

Поэтому, в вашем случае, наверное, вы хотите использовать

```
\A[\p{L}0-9_]+\z
```

Или - если строка может быть пустой:

```
\A[\p{L}0-9_]*\z
```

*Подробности*

- `\A` - начало строки
- `[\p{L}0-9_]+`: - один и более символов из следующего набора:

  - `\p{L}` - любая буква Юникода
  - `0-9` - цифра из набора символов ASCII
  - `_` - знак подчёркивания
- `\z` - конец строки.

Comment: А есть причина использовать именно `\A` вместо `^` и `\z` вместо `$`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Для валидации - да. Значение данных якорей нельзя изменить с помощью флагов/опций, а также `\z` находит только конец строки, тогда как `$` также находит позицию перед последним `\n` в строке (и это без флага `Multiline`).